# Problem with mysql query joining three tables

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a join query, have three tables:
Calculos which is has a field Operador joined by field "Asignado" related to table Operador, Movimientos which is joined throw IdCaso to Id in Cálculos.
The problem is that I field Operador gets Null.

```
SELECT Movimientos.Id as IdMovimientos, 
        Movimientos.Asignado as Operador,Operadores.Id, 
        Operadores.Nombre as Cargo,     
        Movimientos.Fecha,Movimientos.Asignado,
        Movimientos.Estado,Movimientos.Observacion,
        Movimientos.Observacion, 
        Calculos.Nombre,Calculos.Estado,Calculos.Usuario,
        Movimientos.Estado as IdEstado  
FROM `Calculos` 
    INNER JOIN Movimientos on Movimientos.IdCaso=Calculos.Codigo 
    left JOIN Operadores as Operadores on Calculos.Asignado=Operadores.Id 
WHERE Calculos.Codigo=4724 
Order by Fecha Desc
```

Thanks

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If sometimes null then there is missing data in Operadore and is forced to be returned by left JOIN Operadores  -